# IconButton Location change on pressed

Tags: flutter, button

I have a button and when it's pressed it pops a search bar underneath the button but I need this bar pop next to the button and my button should go to the left on pressed.

Comment: Please include images and sources for better understanding

Comment: please include some graphical representation